# React Routing don't change routes path and outlet

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-dom

So i have route as below on the app js

```
import React from "react";
import Login from "./pages/Login";
import { BrowserRouter, Routes, Route } from "react-router-dom";
import Dashboard from "./pages/Dashboard";
import "./App.css";

function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <BrowserRouter>
        <Routes>
          <Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
            <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
            {/* <Route path="*" element={<Login />} /> */}
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </BrowserRouter>
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

it works when the path is "/" its only show the dashboard page, but when i change the path with "/login", instead of showing the login pages it still showing the dashboard pages,can someone explain it to me..., even the "*" not working at all, when i change it into unregisterd path it still showing the dashboard page...

Here is what the sidebar component code:

```
import React, { useState } from "react";
import { Fragment } from "react";
import { Route, Link } from "react-router-dom";

import {
  MdOutlineSpaceDashboard,
  MdOutlineStorage,
  MdOutlineFactCheck,
  MdOutlineCalculate,
  MdStickyNote2,
  MdAssignmentTurnedIn,
  MdOutlineDynamicForm,
  MdOutlineArrowDropDown,
} from "react-icons/md";
import { BsChevronDown, BsArrowLeftShort } from "react-icons/bs";

import Logo_Nabati from "../assets/logo-nabati.svg";

const menuItems = [
  { id: 1, label: "Dashboard", icon: MdOutlineSpaceDashboard, link: "/" },
  {
    id: 2,
    label: "Master Data",
    icon: MdOutlineStorage,
    iconArrow: MdOutlineArrowDropDown,
    link: "",
    subMenu: true,
    subMenuItems: [
      { id: 8, label: "KSBT", link: "/MasterData/list/KSBT" },
      { id: 9, label: "SQ01_RM", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 10, label: "SQ01_PM", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 11, label: "Depre", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 12, label: "OMC", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 13, label: "Premix", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 14, label: "Routing", link: "/MasterData" },
      { id: 15, label: "MP", link: "/MasterData" },
    ],
  },
  { id: 3, label: "Check COGM", icon: MdOutlineFactCheck, link: "/checkcogm" },
  {
    id: 4,
    label: "Calculation",
    icon: MdOutlineCalculate,
    link: "/calculation",
  },
  {
    id: 5,
    label: "Draft Calculation",
    icon: MdStickyNote2,
    link: "/draft",
  },
  { id: 6, label: "Approved", icon: MdAssignmentTurnedIn, link: "/approval" },
  { id: 7, label: "Task Activity", icon: MdOutlineDynamicForm, link: "/task" },
];

const Sidebar = () => {
  const [open, setOpen] = useState(false);
  const [submenuOpen, setSubmenuOpen] = useState(false);
  return (
    <div className="flex">
      <div
        className={` bg-yellow-400 h-screen p-5 pt-8  ${
          open
            ? "w-50 ease-out delay-150 peer-focus:left-0 duration-200"
            : "w-20 ease-out delay-150 peer-focus:left-0 duration-200"
        } duration-300 relative`}
      >
        <BsArrowLeftShort
          className={` bg-white text-yellow-300 text-3xl rounded-full absolute -right-3 top-9 border border-yellow-300 cursor-pointer delay-150 duration-200  ${
            !open && "rotate-180"
          }`}
          onClick={() => setOpen(!open)}
        />
        <div className={`inline-flex`}>
          <img src={Logo_Nabati} width={115} height={65} alt="logo Nabati" />
        </div>
        <ul className="pt-8">
          {menuItems.map(
            ({ icon: Icon, iconArrow: IconArrow, ...menu }, index) => (
              <Fragment key={index}>
                <Link to={menu.link}>
                  <li className="text-white text-sm text-justify flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-2 hover:bg-red-600 rounded-md mt-2">
                    <Icon className="text-2xl text-white group-hover:text-red-600" />

                    <span
                      className={`text-base font-mendium flex-1 duration-200 ${
                        !open && "hidden"
                      } `}
                    >
                      {menu.label}
                    </span>
                    {menu.subMenu && (
                      <BsChevronDown
                        className={`text-base font-mendium  duration-200 ${
                          !open && "hidden"
                        } ${submenuOpen && "rotate-180"}`}
                        onClick={() => {
                          setSubmenuOpen(!submenuOpen);
                        }}
                      />
                    )}
                  </li>{" "}
                </Link>
                {menu.subMenu && submenuOpen && open && (
                  <ul>
                    {menu.subMenuItems.map((subMenuItem, j) => (
                      <Link to={subMenuItem.link}>
                        <li
                          key={subMenuItem.id}
                          className="text-white text-sm flex items-center gap-x-4 cursor-pointer p-0.5 px-12 hover:bg-red-500 rounded-md"
                        >
                          {subMenuItem.label}
                        </li>{" "}
                      </Link>
                    ))}
                  </ul>
                )}
              </Fragment>
            )
          )}
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Sidebar;
```

and here is the dashboard page:

```
import Layout from "../containers/layout";

const Dashboard = () => {
  return (
    <Layout>
      <>Dasboard</>
    </Layout>
  );
};
export default Dashboard;
```

here is the layout page:

```
import { Sidebar } from "../components";

const Layout = ({ children }) => {
  return (
    <div className="flex flex-row justify-start">
      <Sidebar />
      <div className="bg-white flex-1 pl-4 pt-4 w-full  text-red-600">
        {children}
<Outlet/>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Layout;
```

here is my login page:

```
import { FaUser, FaLock, FaUserLock } from "react-icons/fa";
import logo_nabati from "../assets/logo-nabati.svg";
import { connect } from "react-redux";
import { useState, useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import { useDispatch, useSelector } from "react-redux";

const required = (value) => {
  if (!value) {
    return (
      <div className="alert alert-danger" role="alert">
        This field is required!
      </div>
    );
  }
};
const Login = (props) => {
  const initState = {
    newAttribs: { ...props.test },
  };
  const form = useRef();
  const checkBtn = useRef();

  const [userList, setUserList] = useState(initState);
  const [username, setUsername] = useState("");
  const [password, setPassword] = useState("");
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();

  useEffect(() => {
    setUserList((userList) => ({
      ...userList,
      newAttribs: { ...props.test },
    }));
  }, [props.test]);

  const onChangeUsername = (e) => {
    const username = e.target.value;
    setUsername(username);
  };

  const onChangePassword = (e) => {
    const password = e.target.value;
    setPassword(password);
  };

  console.log("userList now", userList);

  const loginSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    console.log("====================================");
    console.log(username, password);
    console.log("====================================");
  };
  return (
    <div>
      {/* container */}
      <div className="bg-gradient-to-r from-yellow-400 block h-screen items-center justify-center p-4 pt-32 md:flex">
        {/* login.card */}
        <div className=" bg-no-repeat bg-left bg-image flex flex-col items-center max-w-screen-lg overflow-hidden rounded-lg shadow-lg text-white w-full md:flex-row">
          {/* logo */}
          <div className="backdrop-blur-sm backdrop-filter flex flex-col items-center justify-center p-4 text-dark w-full md:w-1/2">
            <h1 className="font-medium text-3xl">COGM Calculation</h1>
            <p className="italic text-lg">For Manufacturing Cost Controller</p>
          </div>
          {/* form */}
          <div className="bg-white flex flex-col items-center p-4 space-y-8 w-full md:w-1/2">
            {/* title */}
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center">
              <h1 className="font-medium text-yellow-500 text-xl">Welcome</h1>{" "}
              <img
                className="m-2"
                src={logo_nabati}
                width={123}
                height={75}
                alt="logo Nabati"
              />
              <p className="text-gray-600">
                <strong>Login to COGM Page</strong>
              </p>
            </div>
            {/* input */}
            <form
              onSubmit={loginSubmit}
              className="flex flex-col items-center space-y-3 pt-0"
            >
              <div className="relative">
                <span className="absolute flex inset-y-0 items-center pl-4 text-gray-400">
                  <FaUser></FaUser>
                </span>
                <input
                  className="border border-gray-300 outline-none text-black placeholder-gray-400 pl-9 pr-4 py-1 rounded-md transition focus:ring-2 focus:ring-yellow-300"
                  placeholder="Username...."
                  type="text"
                  onChange={onChangeUsername}
                  validations={[required]}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div className="relative">
                <span className="absolute flex inset-y-0 items-center pl-4 text-gray-400">
                  <FaLock></FaLock>
                </span>
                <input
                  className="border border-gray-300 outline-none text-black placeholder-gray-400 pl-9 pr-4 py-1 rounded-md transition focus:ring-2 focus:ring-yellow-300"
                  placeholder="Password...."
                  type="password"
                  onChange={onChangePassword}
                  validations={[required]}
                ></input>
              </div>
              <div className="items-left">
                <button
                  className="bg-yellow-500 font-medium inline-flex items-center px-3 py-1 rounded-md shadow-sm text-white hover:bg-yellow-600 pr-100"
                  type="submit"
                  ref={checkBtn}
                >
                  <FaUserLock className="mr-2"></FaUserLock>
                  Sign In
                </button>
              </div>
            </form>
            {/* button Link */}
            <div className="flex flex-col items-center text-gray-600">
              <p className="italic">Forget password</p>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};
const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
  test: state.Auth,
});
export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Login);
```

when i put the outlet on the layout page, it turn my page into this:
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

(I suppose you're using React Router v6)

Because your login route is inside of the dashboard:

```js
<Route exact path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
  <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
</Route>
```

Just move the nested login outside: (there is no `exact` in v6)

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />} />
  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
</Routes>
```

If you want to have some nested routes in your Dashboard, like `/dashboard/profile`:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Dashboard />}>
    <Route path="profile" element={<Profile />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
</Routes>
```

---

[Update] I think this is probably what you want:

```js
<Routes>
  <Route path="/" element={<Layout />}>
    <Route index element={<Dashboard />} />
  </Route>
  <Route path="login" element={<Login />} />
</Routes>
```

In this case you don't need the `{children}` in your Layout.

Comment: now the problem is the dashboard component move below the layout..

Comment: If you're not using Layout in the route definitions, remove the `<Outlet/>` from Layout.

Comment: One more option is to define the Layout in your routes. I've added the example in the answer.

Comment: it works, can you explain to me why react doom v6 is a bit confusing that we have to use oulet

Comment: Here has some explanations from the react-router team https://twitter.com/MustafaHaddara/status/1456048868752252929